# PHP active Menu for Get['id']

Tags: php, menu

I use menu system for page's `$_GET['id']` but my codes dont work. How can i do it ?

My codes below

functions.php

```
function header_menu ($page) {
        echo "<ul>";
        if($page){
         echo "<li><a href='index.php'><span>Home</span></a></li>";
        }else {
         echo "<li><a class='active' href=\"index.php\"><span>Home</span></a></li>";
        }
        include ('admin/dbbaglan.php'); 
        $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sayfalar ORDER BY sira ASC");
        while($pages=mysql_fetch_array($sql1)) {
            if($page == $pages[id]) {
             echo "<li><a class=\"active\" href=\"index.php?pages={$pages['id']}\">{$pages['isim']}</a></li>\n";
            }else {
             echo "<li><a href=\"index.php?pages={$pages['id']}\">{$pages['isim']}</a></li>\n";
            }

        }
echo "</ul>";                   
}
```

i show menu functions in header.php

```
<?php 
include 'functions.php'; 
header_menu($_GET[page]); 
?>
```

But no active menu when page is active

Comment: You've not quoted `'id'` in `$pages` under the while loop. Same for 'page' in $_GET. Although that will technically work it will produce an error notice. http://3v4l.org/EH5hq

Comment: Have you made sure you are actually passing it in the $_GET? e.g. /header.php?page=test

Comment: What you need to do is follow it back. You say your problem is that you're not getting the active class. Well, that means your condition in the while loop returned false. So what are the contents of the two sides of your condition, `$page` and `$pages['id']`?

Comment: what do u what to pass to the function?? $_GET['page'] or $_GET['id']??on the question it is 'id' but 'page' is passed.

Comment: @bcmcfc $pages['id'] for example url index.php?id=6 , index.php?id=8, index.php?id=4 etc.. I want to active buton for example index.php?id=8 page. so ı have to use while loop and then in the while loop, I have to use if condition but i take mistake return false